# React Native Error: Ambiguous resolution

Tags: xcode, react-native, node-modules

When I try to run my React Native app on the iOS simulator, I'm presented with a red screen with the following error:

> Ambiguous resolution: module
>   '/Users/my-user/Documents/my-RN-app/app/index.js' tries to require
>   'react-native-vector-icons', but there are several files providing
>   this module. You can delete or fix them:
>
> /Users/my-user/Documents/my-RN-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/my-RN-app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json
>
> /Users/my-user/Documents/my-RN-app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json

However, both of those above files (the package.json files) are missing. I had actually gotten this error before, so I decided to delete the package.json file in the first directory location mentioned above (under ios/build/.. etc.) and refreshed the app and it loaded just fine. Now, after trying to start up my app again in the iOS simulator, I am back to the same error, but I cannot delete the package.json file because it doesn't even exist now in either location.

I've tried to just comment out the import of the `react-native-vector-icons` lib in my app/index.js file and restarting the sim, but the error still appears.

So finally, I've tried this:

1. `sudo rm -rf node_modules` (I get "permission denied" if I don't use `sudo` although it appears I have full read/write permission on all the files/folders in this project)
2. `sudo rm -rf ios/build`
3. `npm install`
4. `cd ios && pod install`
5. `react-native link`

And then back into Xcdoe: Product > Clean, after which I ran the simulator again. Still the same error.

As requested, here is my package.json file:

```
 {
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "run-ios": "node_modules/.bin/react-native run-ios",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "art": "^0.10.1",
    "auto-bind": "^1.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.3.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "native-base": "^2.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "pubnub": "^4.18.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.49.3",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-fabric": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-fingerprint-scanner": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-flip-card": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^5.3.3",
    "react-native-haptic": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-keychain": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-mplayer": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-notifications-badge-extensions": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-permissions": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-pie": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.26",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-tag-input": "0.0.18",
    "react-native-tooltip": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-uuid-generator": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-voice": "^0.2.5",
    "react-navigation": "^1.2.0",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.0.3",
    "validator": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint": "^3.14.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "jest-serializer-enzyme": "^1.0.0",
    "jsdom": "11.6.2",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "metro-bundler": "^0.20.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-native-mock": "^0.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "sinon": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.19.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your `package.json`. Also consider reading through [this issue](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/626). In particular, check out [this comment](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/626#issuecomment-357405396) as that issue might be related to what you're running into.

Comment: Try `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: Michael: I've posted my `package.json` above, but the comment you linked to may have helped (it didn't solve the issue, but I deleted the file it suggested anyway, and then ran the commands below, and now I'm good).
Mukesh: I tried running that command and it seemed to have done the trick. Here's what I ran, in order: `rm -rf ios/build` `pod install` `react-native link` and then finally `npm start -- --reset-cache` and then I started up the sim and no errors, yay!

Comment: Nvm, spoke too soon. The app started, and then I tried to start the remote debugger as well, and now I'm getting a similar error, except now with `tries to require react-native` instead of `react-native-vector-icons`. I opened up xcode and did Product > Clean and tried to launch the app through xcode (instead of with the react native cli) and now it's working... I'm so confused on what the root problem actually is.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, this might help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737251/how-do-i-prevent-react-native-device-info-causing-react-ambiguity-on-my-setup/52776146#52776146

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually link the React pod to `node_modules`:

`pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'`

Then clean and build again

Comment: Brilliant, but I found I also needed to add a subspecs section!