# How do I prevent react-native-device-info causing React ambiguity on my setup?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-device-info

I'm running into a problem with installing `react-native-device-info` into an existing react-native project (created using `create-react-native-app` and then ejecting)

I run:

`yarn add react-native-device-info
yarn install
react-native link react-native-device-info
cd ios && pod install & cd ..`

pod install installs `RNDeviceInfo`, but also `React` as a dependency?

I then run `yarn ios` as normal.

The MetroBundler fails with:

```
This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: ambiguous resolution: module `/Users/thomasclarke/dev/mobile-notifications-native/index.js` tries to require `react-native`, but there are several files providing this module. You can delete or fix them:

- `/Users/thomasclarke/dev/mobile-notifications-native/ios/Pods/React/package.json`
- `/Users/thomasclarke/dev/mobile-notifications-native/node_modules/react-native/package.json`
  ```

I've raised a bug report, as this is clearly unacceptable behaviour, but is this something I can work around with my setup?

Comment: Thanks to @chris-feist for the answer below!

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that you can link to the react-native in your node_modules, which provides the necessary dependency. This was not done by default in the existing project, so here is the process:

1) Start from "clean" (e.g. with no `react-native-device-info` behaviour). Having messed around before this, I also found I had to clear out both my `node_modules` and my `ios/Pods` directories to clear out the legacy React package.

2) Update your Podfile to link to React (you will also have to add in any [relevant subspecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775976/how-can-i-know-which-react-native-pod-subspecs-to-add) and a separate pod for Yoga)

Here are the lines to add to your podfile:

  `pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'DevSupport',
    'Core',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText'
  ]
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'`

3) Then run `react-native link react-native-device-info`

This will add react-native-device-info to your Podfile (along with android setup)

`pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'`

4) Install everything as normal:

`yarn install
cd ios
pod install`

And you should now have a functioning build!

Comment: sorry sir. is it possible to apply your solution to my question here? just thought it might be the same issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537990/react-native-from-a-library-project-how-to-import-and-use-a-packages-module

Comment: @jerinho It does look similar, I recommend backing up your project and giving it a go.