# How can I know which React Native pod subspecs to add?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, podfile

Working on an issue where I needed to add the `react-native-device-info` package to my iOS system, I had to add a dependency on React into my Podfile.

Initially I applied all the podspecs from a list I'd found on the net:

```
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'DevSupport',
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]
```

But I realised that some of those would likely be unnecessary, and via trial and error whittled it down to:

```
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'DevSupport',
    'Core',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText'
  ]
```

My question is *how can I work out which subspecs are necessary and why?*

Also hoping the answer to this will give me a better understanding of what's going on when I use subspecs.