# React Native - From a library project, how to import and use a package's module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've created a React Native library project using `react-native-create-library` command to give my development more modular environment, so later I may use that library for multiple ongoing application projects and eliminate code repetition. For Java it is working great especially for external app activity invocation, file uploading, and event and gesture handling.

The problem is when I try to include Javascript code in library project. At begin when I just try to import it like usual, Metro Bundler show this error

> Unable to resolve module `react` from
>   `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\link\react-native-library\JSLib.js`:
>   Module `react` does not exist in the Haste module map

I'm quickly assumed that the reason is because beside a `.yarn-integrity` file, library project has no any packages inside it's `node_modules` directory. So I've tried to do `yarn add react` to load it up with react packages. After recompile from application project, Metro Bundler now show this error

> bundling failed: ambiguous resolution: module C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test\index.js tries to require react-native, but there are several files providing this module. You can delete or fix them:
>
> *C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\link\react-native-library\node_modules\react-native\package.json
>
> *C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test\node_modules\react-native\package.json

I've raised the issue [here](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library/issues/89) but yet to find any solution. The best response is the one saying we can't symlink to a package.

All I need to know is how to use a package's module from a library project. Any responses or helps are much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

I have tried `yarn add --peer`. It's working for **react** but not for other dependencies like **react-navigation** and others.

I'd see some other packages like for example **react-native-modal** simply put other dependencies like **react-native-animatable** for example, as a **"not peer"** dependency in **package.json**. When it is installed into application project, both are been put into application's **node_modules** and they're working fine.

But if I install dependency directly to application project to imitate how production installation works, it's failed with same error. The difference between them is on my project it use symlink reference (called **junction** on **Windows**).

So I assume either symlinking is the issue here or something I've missed which I have no clue at all.